# How to find 10 random decimal numbers between min number and max number , the sum of random numbers should be X

Tags: java, spring-boot, logic, arithmetic-expressions

to find 10 random decimal numbers between 7.00 and 13.00, the sum of the 10 random decimal numbers should be 100.

I have tried and I am getting the total sum but I am not getting the random number between range

```
public class TenRandomNumber {
    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double m = 10;
        double n = 100;

        double arr[] = new double[(int) m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double t=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(7.00,13.00) * m;

            arr[(int) t]++;
        }

        int totalCount = (int) m;

        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {

            if (i == (totalCount - 1)) {

                arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(df.format(arr[i] - ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 1)));
                total = total + arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i] + n - total;

            } else {
                arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(df.format(arr[i] - ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 1)));

                total = total + arr[i];
            }

            System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `while(total != 100) { // continue to generate random numbers }`.  I would imagine you could improve on that algorithm in a number of ways: by replacing smaller numbers if you're less than 100, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks we have tried this but we did not get the numbers between 7 and 13.

Comment: So what *did* you get?

Comment: @user207421 i am geeting 13.8 
11.19 
22.74 
17.29 
9.49 
2.01 
4.23 
2.63 
6.49 
10.12

Comment: That's because you multiplied the result of `nextDouble()` by 10 when it was already in range. I also don't know why you're calling `nextDouble()` so many times, or why you are formatting and then parsing doubles. Reconsider all this.

Answer (score 1):

By dynamically calculating the feasible range of current random number, we can obtain the desired result in few tries.

```java
class Main {
    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] result = safeGeneration(7, 13, 100, 10);
        double sum = 0;
        for (double d : result) sum += d;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
    private static double[] safeGeneration(double min, double max, double totalSum, int count) {
        // Some argument validation may be required here
        while(true) {
            try {
                return generateRandoms(min, max, totalSum, count);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // In case that bad randoms are given, try again.
            }
        }
    }
    private static double[] generateRandoms(double min, double max, double totalSum, int count) {
        double currentSum = 0;
        double[] array = new double[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            // The minimum possible value for next random number that allows the rest numbers to stay in range.
            double coerceMin = (totalSum - currentSum - max * (10 - i - 1));
            // The maximum possible value for next random number that allows the rest numbers to stay in range.
            double coerceMax = (totalSum - currentSum - min * (10 - i - 1));

            coerceMin = Math.max(coerceMin, min);
            coerceMax = Math.min(coerceMax, max);
            double nextRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(coerceMin, coerceMax);
            nextRandom = Double.parseDouble(df.format(nextRandom));
            currentSum += nextRandom;
            array[i] = nextRandom;
        }
        array[count - 1] = Double.parseDouble(df.format(totalSum - currentSum));
        return array;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[8.05, 12.56, 12.97, 11.61, 9.4, 8.92, 9.07, 9.61, 7.54, 10.27]
Sum: 100.0
```